# What is the purpose of the pig at the hub?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

There is a small pig, named Poogie, hanging out at the hub area. I can interact with it by petting it, but it gets an exclamation point over its head, briefly followed by the little bulging vein symbol signifying anger. It then knocks me over.

Am I supposed to do something to appease the pig? Or is there some other purpose to it?

Comment: It's not "the pig"... It's Poogie! It's the best thing in the franchise!

Comment: I've edited my question to include Poogie's name. Being new to the series, I can imagine other noobs might not know of Poogie's name, its reputation, or anything else about it, so I stand by my referring to it as "the pig" since 1: it is in fact a pig and 2: it's the only pig in the hub area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you press X on PS4 or A on Xbox One when the exclamation mark appears, the Poogie will do a happy dance and grunt in approval. This <s>increases the chances of obtaining rare items from quests</s> can be repeated multiple time until eventually Poogie will befriend you.

Once you're Poogie's friend, you can pick him up and carry him around, change his costumes, and change his name. While carrying Poogie around, certain places will make the controller rumble. If you put Poogie down at these spots, he will dig an item out for you.

Comment: Being brand new to the series, I had to Google to understand why the stricken text was included, since it's simply a rumor. I appreciate the response though!

Comment: The Poogie Petting minigame is also there to help train players on how to use the cooking spit, as it teaches listening to audio/visual cues, without the risk of burnt meat.

Comment: Pigs digging up treasure? Hrm, now [where have I heard that before?](http://www.piranhazone.com/images/zelda/ww/gc/0050_1.jpg)

Comment: A little hint on the PS4 button. For the German version, the right button is O and not X. I am not quite shure about other versions, but X is right for the Japanese version